# java Calculating the mean average

Tags: java

I am trying to do the following java assignment and every thing seems to work fine except when I put a number<4 or >10 it prints both "Invalid grade!"
"You didn't enter any data!" what I wanted is to print only "Invalid grade!" I tried to fix it but I couldn't. Can any one help me please?

Thanks,

**Assignment:**
Create a program that asks for results of exams and calculates the mean average of the grades. Grades are floating point numbers between 4 and 10. Program asks for grades until a negative number is typed. If user gives a grade other than a number between 4 and 10, the text “Invalid grade!” will be printed on screen and program asks for another grade. Finally the program prints the number of inputted grades and their mean average on screen as shown in the example print. If no grades were inputted, the notice “You did not input any grades.” is the only thing printed on screen.

Hint:A double type variable is to be used to store the value of the average.

Program is written to a class called Average.

Example output

Program calculates the average of inputted grades.
Finish with a negative integer.

```
Input a grade (4-10): 5
Input a grade (4-10): 6,5
Input a grade (4-10): 7,5
Input a grade (4-10): 7
Input a grade (4-10): 0
Invalid grade!
Input a grade (4-10): -4

4 grades inputted.

Average of the grades: 6.5
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class apples {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      int inputNumber=0;   
      int sum;           
      int count;         
      double average;    



      sum = 0;
      count = 0;


      Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Program calculates the average of inputted grades.");
      System.out.println("Finish with a negative integer.");
      System.out.print("Input a grade (4-10): ");
      inputNumber = reader.nextInt();


      while (inputNumber > 0 && inputNumber>=4 && inputNumber<=10) {
         sum += inputNumber;   
         count++;              
         System.out.print("Input a grade (4-10): ");
         inputNumber = reader.nextInt();

      }

      if (inputNumber<4 || inputNumber>10) {
          System.out.println("Invalid grade!");
      }

      if (count==0) {
          System.out.print("You didn't enter any data!");
      }
      else {
         average = ((double)sum) / count;
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println(count + " grades inputted.");
         System.out.print("Average of the grades: "+ average);
      }

   } 

}
```

Comment: add a `return;` into the `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, an `if - else` will help here, but where you put it also matters.

```
    while (inputNumber > 0) {
        if (inputNumber<4 || inputNumber>10) {
            System.out.println("Invalid grade!");
        } else {
            sum += inputNumber;
            count++;
        }
        System.out.print("Input a grade (4-10): ");
        inputNumber = reader.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, I edited my code based on your suggestion but the output is not the same. when I enter 0 it tells me "You didn't enter any data!" but what I want is the out put to be "You didn't enter any data!" and continue to ask for more grades. once again thank you.

Comment: Change the while condition to be `inputNumber >= 0` This will print "Invalid Grade" and then prompt you for another grade.

Answer (score 3):

Put an else in before the second if, so it is only done if the first one was not:

```
if (inputNumber<4 || inputNumber>10) {
    System.out.println("Invalid grade!");
} else if (count==0) {
    System.out.print("You didn't enter any data!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you finish with a negative integer the inputNumber will always be less than 4 so

```
if (inputNumber<4 || inputNumber>10) {
      System.out.println("Invalid grade!");
  }
```

is always true.

Change it to following (slightly easier to read):

```
 do {    
      System.out.print("Input a grade (4-10): ");
      inputNumber = reader.nextInt(); 
      if (inputNumber<4 || inputNumber>10) {
         break ; // 
      }
    sum += inputNumber;   
    count++;              


  }while (count <= 4) {

  if (count==0) {
      System.out.print("You didn't enter any data!");
  }
```

Comment: Aha: Missed the original requirement :" If user gives a grade other than a number between 4 and 10, the text “Invalid grade!” will be printed on screen and program asks for another grade." So the break; should be replaced by a continue or keep the loop and see Don Temple's solution.

Comment: One thing about Dan's suggestion : if you enter a 0 as the first grade it will not enter the loop : Change the algorithm to a do-while                                                                                  `do {
   read input
  if( negative)
      break
 if(  between 4 and 10 )
      process sum and count
  else
     message 
} while ( some condition (maybe count <= 4 ) )

if( count == 0 )
....`

Answer (score 0):

As this is an assignment, I'd prefer to give you a clue rather than the answer..

Take a close look at your while loop - it's never being entered. 
This means count is 0 when you input, for example, 3. As it's executing, you are meeting both conditions which means both lines are being printed. You'll need to modify the code to make sure that one or the other condition is met (or reached), but not both.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total = 0;
        double number_sum = 0, number_entered = 0, avg = 0;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .print("Program calculates the average of inputted grades. \nFinish with a negative integer.\n\n");
        do {
            System.out.print("Input a grade (4-10): ");
            number_entered = reader.nextDouble();
            if (number_entered <= 10 && number_entered >= 4) {
                number_sum = number_sum + number_entered;
                total++;
            }
            if (number_entered == 0 || number_entered < 4
                    || number_entered > 10) {

                System.out.print("Invalid grade!");
                System.out.print("\nInput a grade (4-10): ");
                number_entered = reader.nextDouble();
            }
            if (number_entered < 0) {
                if (total == 0) {
                    System.out.print("You did not input any grades.");
                } else {
                    avg = number_sum / total;
                    System.out.print(total + " grades inputted.\n");
                    System.out.print("Average of the grades: " + avg);
                }
            }
        } while (number_entered > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Please don't just give people code, give them pointers. 2) Please format your code.